specifying the python version to use to run a dataflow pipeline
is it possible to force a dataflow job to run with a specific version of python?
I have some dependencies that are only supported from python 3.11

How do you start the dataflow job? Are you using a (flex) template? Do you start it directly from the console using python ... etc?

The Python workers will use the same (major) version of Python that was used to launch the main program. If you submit your job with Python 3.11, the dataflow workers will run on Python 3.11.
